# Significant total effect but non significant direct and indirect effects

Tags: mediation

I used Hayes' PROCESS macro Model 4 to look at mediation and the results reveal a significant total effect but non significant indirect and direct effects. What could cause this? Is it a power issue? My sample size was $\sim160$

Total effect of $X$ on $Y$

```
Effect .3200   SE .1251   t   2.5572   p   .0115   LLCI .0729 ULCI  .5671
```

Direct effect of $X$ on $Y$

```
Effect .1582    SE  .0847    t 1.8683   p  .0635  LLCI   -.0090 ULCI  .3253
```

Indirect effect of $X$ on $Y$

```
Effect .1619     Boot SE  .0954    BootLLCI  -.0141  BootULCI .3563
```

Comment: It means you have evidence that there is a global effect, but you don't have evidence neither of a direct effect or an indirect effect. Please remember that a non-significant effect is not evidence of lack of an effect. As for power, of course with a larger sample, if the same estimates resisted, you would get signfiicant results (as long as they are not $0$, there exists a large enough sample to make them significant). An example similar to what you describe is when you have a significant difference between two effects, but there's overlap between their confidence intervals.